# What's the difference between importScripts and ES6 modules/import?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, es6-modules

I currently implement a front-end along with a service worker.
As I require several code pieces for my service worker, I opted to use the [importScripts](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#importscripts) function from the standard.

I really don't get why importScripts was added to this standard as [modules](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) became part of the ES6 standard about 3 years ago (although still missing in most browsers, if not using a flag).

Can someone elaborate on this?
I assume it's related to the error handling and the like...

Answer (score 17):

After some research the bottomline is, that the specification for importScripts was older than for the ES6 modules. In the long run ES6 modules [likely will be supported](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#module-worker-example) in Service Workers. As of now it's [not supported in Chrome Canary yet](https://twitter.com/Valio_ch/status/882241991559573504), although there is ES6 module support for the front-end since version 60.